# Time being allowed before start time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to stop a user selecting the end date to be not before the start date so I thought a compare valdiator would work. But its still allowing them to put in a time earlier than the start time before it triggers the validation rule. I am using a datepicker with time element to allow the user to pick.

I guess I am asking does there need be a different way of doing this cause of the time element obv if both the same date it wouldnt find if the times where different?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_bio">Start Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-7">
        <telerik:RadDateTimePicker OnSelectedDateChanged="rdStarDate_SelectedDateChanged" AutoPostBackControl="Calendar" ID="rdStarDate" DateInput-CausesValidation="true" DateInput-AutoPostBack="true" Calendar-AutoPostBack="false" TimeView-Width="200px" Width="200px" CssClass="pickerDateInputClass no-border" runat="server" Skin="Bootstrap">
            <TimeView CellSpacing="-1" StartTime="9:00:00" runat="server" Culture="en-GB" EndTime="18:00:00" Interval="00:30"></TimeView>
        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_bio">End Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpVal1" ControlToCompare="rdStarDate"
                          ControlToValidate="rdEndDate" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ForeColor="Red" Display="Static"
                          ErrorMessage="*End Date Cannot be less then Start Date" runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>

    <div class="input-group col-md-7">
        <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdEndDate" DateInput-CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBackControl="TimeView" TimeView-Width="200px" Width="200px" DateInput-AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="pickerDateInputClass no-border" runat="server" Skin="Bootstrap">
            <TimeView CellSpacing="-1" runat="server" StartTime="9:00:00" Culture="en-GB" EndTime="18:00:00" Interval="00:30"></TimeView>
        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 2**
As in screen shot here when i change the date back to one thats forward the validator is still showing

The vaidator stays visible even if i reset the date to one that is greater than or equal to the origianl

[image]

Comment: thank you @rashfmnb for the code edit

Answer (score 0):

When the start date is picked set this.

rdEndDate.MinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdStarDate.SelectedDate);

Comment: why would i do that spirfire2k6 what as mine date to do with it ?.

Comment: When you set the MinDate, any date before that is un-selectable.

Comment: But if i changed the start date to a different one that wouldnt really help the situation

Comment: You can add this to the onchange event on the start date piacker.

Comment: Does not solve the problem therefore wont be voting this solution sorry.

Comment: please see changes to question to explain futher the validtor is still showing even though i reset my end date